# Upgrading libGdx and Gradle project results in build errors

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I have an older libGdx project that uses version 1.9.1 and Gradle 2.4. I`ve tried upgrade to libGdx 1.9.11 and Gradle 6.5. But I get the following build error:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
> - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.1

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `jcenter()` in your root `build.gradle` file

```
repositories {
        jcenter()   // <- Add this
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        google()
    }
```

Then sync your project with gradle file. Make sure gradle is not in offline mode and you've good network connection.